What are the Adventure League Rules Governing the Trading of an Arrow of Slaying?
According to Season 14 Adventures League Rules, characters are allowed to trade permanent magic items:

Permanent magic items can be traded. Unique magic items may not be
traded. Trading permanent magic items with other characters in your
character’s campaign is on a one-for-one basis of equivalent rarity.
You cannot trade with characters attached to a campaign world other
than the one you’ve chosen for your character.

In the DMG p 152, an Arrow of Slaying is listed as:
Weapon (arrow) very rare
The text in the description goes on to state the once the arrow is used, it becomes a nonmagical arrow. Additionally, the text refers to "other types of magic ammunition of the kind exist, etc.." which effectively infers that this is a type of ammunition.
Since this is a permanent magic item (until used) would this be able to be traded for another permanent, very rare, magic item such as a Helm of Brilliance, which functions in a similar way in that, once a spell is cast via one of the helm's magical gems, the gem is destroyed. Thus, both magic items have a finite number of uses.
What about other very rare permanent magic items such as a Tome of Understanding (single use) or a Staff of Power (multiple use)?

permanent magic item (until used)

The arrow may be borrowed or lent but not traded
According to the Season 14 Rules (March 2024)

• Equipment and consumable items can be lent to other characters during play but must return at the end of the session (unless it’s been consumed or lost).
• Permanent magic items can be traded (see below). Unique magic items may not be traded.

Thus permanent magic items may be traded (unless unique), following the rules for trading - but consumable items may not be traded, only lent or borrowed.
The arrows are consumable items, as defined in the same document with emphasis mine:

Consumable items include any magic item that is consumed if used (potions, scrolls, etc.); this includes single-use items (elemental gem, etc.) and charms.

The Adventure's League rules provide a more comprehensive definition than the DMG and make it clear that the single-use arrow of slaying is, by definition, a consumable item, and thus is ineligible for trading.
Note: Although this answer draws upon the AL Year 14 rules, it was directly informed by the accepted answer to the question Is ammunition a consumable magic item? That answer cited the Year 13 AL rules.
